# D3DXCreateTextureFromFile upside down and not centered

Tags: c++, directx

I'm new to directx and finally I managed to load an image which I want to display as background image/texture

Defining image

```
void setBGImage(std::string path)
{
    D3DXCreateTextureFromFileA(m_Device, path.c_str(), &m_BGImage);
    m_BGImageCenter = D3DXVECTOR3(450.0f, 250.0f, 0.0f); // Image is 900x500
}
```

Drawing image

```
void DrawBackground()
{
    m_Sprite->Begin(D3DXSPRITE_OBJECTSPACE|D3DXSPRITE_DONOTMODIFY_RENDERSTATE);

    // Texture tiling
    /*
    D3DXMATRIX texScaling;
    D3DXMatrixScaling(&texScaling, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    m_Device->SetTransform(D3DTS_TEXTURE0, &texScaling);*/

    //D3DXMATRIX T, S, R;
    //D3DXMatrixTranslation(&T, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    //D3DXMatrixScaling(&S, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    //D3DXMatrixRotationZ(&R, 0.45f);
    //m_Sprite->SetTransform(&(S*T));


    m_Sprite->Draw(m_BGImage, 0, &m_BGImageCenter, 0, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 255));
    m_Sprite->Flush();

    m_Sprite->End();
}
```

onResetDevice (is getting called at startup)

```
void onResetDevice()
{
    m_Sprite->OnResetDevice();

    // Sets up the camera 640 units back looking at the origin.
    D3DXMATRIX V;
    D3DXVECTOR3 pos(0.0f, 0.0f, -640.0f); // This distance is just a test value to get only the image and no white background/border as soon as I have it centered I will adjust it.
    D3DXVECTOR3 up(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    D3DXVECTOR3 target(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    D3DXMatrixLookAtLH(&V, &pos, &target, &up);
    m_Device->SetTransform(D3DTS_VIEW, &V);

    // The following code defines the volume of space the camera sees.
    D3DXMATRIX P;
    RECT R;
    GetClientRect(m_hWnd, &R);
    float width  = (float)R.right;
    float height = (float)R.bottom;
    D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(&P, D3DX_PI*0.25f, width/height, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    m_Device->SetTransform(D3DTS_PROJECTION, &P);

    // This code sets texture filters, which helps to smooth out disortions when you scale a texture.
    m_Device->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MAGFILTER, D3DTEXF_LINEAR);
    m_Device->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MINFILTER, D3DTEXF_LINEAR);
    m_Device->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MIPFILTER, D3DTEXF_LINEAR);

    // This line of code disables Direct3D lighting.
    m_Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_LIGHTING, false);

    // The following code specifies an alpha test and reference value.
    m_Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHAREF, 10);
    m_Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHAFUNC, D3DCMP_GREATER);

    // The following code is used to setup alpha blending.
    m_Device->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAARG1, D3DTA_TEXTURE);
    m_Device->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAOP, D3DTOP_SELECTARG1);
    m_Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_SRCBLEND, D3DBLEND_SRCALPHA);
    m_Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_DESTBLEND, D3DBLEND_INVSRCALPHA);

    // Indicates that we are using 2D texture coordinates.
    m_Device->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_TEXTURETRANSFORMFLAGS, D3DTTFF_COUNT2);
}
```

When I use these methods to render my background image it get's displayed upside down, not centered (little bit to the right) and I've got the feeling the height width ratio isn't correct (image is kinda blurry and it feels like the image is not as high as it's supposed to be).

[image]

What did I try?

I tried to adjust various coordinates in order to look at the image from the other side and then rotate it but whatever I tried it turned into a white/non-existing background.

Centering the image is not such a big deal I can just move the camera position but I'm confused since the `m_BGImageCenter` was supposed to do that for me in the Draw method and it seems to not work 100% correct.

My Questions (I guess it's ok to ask multiple questions in this context):

How can I get the image not upside down (I know how you would do it in theory but I somehow don't get it right, so please give me the coordinates).

Why is the image not centered?

Is it possible that `D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH` is wrapping my image since it looks a little bit blurry.

Comment: Why do you use `D3DXSPRITE_OBJECTSPACE`at all? Drawing a background with perspective seems a bit odd. This is probably a reason why the results are wrong. If you insist on using your own matrix, use an orthographic projection.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, at least this fixed the upside down effect and the not being centered part. It's somehow zoomed but I guess I'll be able to fix this on my own. Nevertheless I will leave this question open since it still bugs me why this is happening.

Comment: You might be able to find more people who know about this kind of thing on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ perhaps?